# VueJS 3 See all globally registered components. this.$options.components is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-options-api

Hello I have a new Vue 3 app using Vite.
I'm registering my `UserTextInput` component globally but inside all my components `this.$options.components` is empty

```
import UserTextInput from "./components/defaultComponents/UserTextInput.vue";

const app = createApp(App);
app.component('UserTextInput', UserTextInput);
app.mount('#app');
```

Inside any other component

```
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options.components); // {} empty object
  },
```

I'm looking for a way to see what components have been registered globally.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I found the list stored here in my Vue 3 app:

`app._instance.appContext.components`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

getCurrentInstance().appContext.components // this will list all component registered globally
```